# How to redirect the lasers in Testchamber 19 in Chapter 4?

Tags: portal-2

I'm stuck again, this time in Testchamber 19 in Chapter 4.

[image]

I've used the cubicle on the ground to change the angle of the laser on the right. I also know there's are cubicles to the left and right of where you enter Testchamber 19.

[image]

But I couldn't find a way to make use of Portals to get to get to those cubicles. So any hints as to what I should do next?

Comment: Just below the middle of both your screenshots there is one of those panels that throws you in to the air, with a handy portal-taking ceiling directly above it - I found that very helpful for launching myself to get hold of otherwise hard to reach objects....

Comment: Because of those annoying blue circles on the ceiling I actually thought it didn't take Portals. Guess I've been taking visual clues the wrong way ;-)

Comment: The blue circles signal the landing point of the plate. (FYI)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You have already obtained the first cube, which was on the floor.
- Obtain the cube to your left, at the ceiling you can place a Portal and then walk into a wall.

[image]

- Obtain the second cube by using the aerial faith plate. Place a portal above it and on the floor, then in mid-air fire another portal to where I aimed the cursor.

[image]

- Then, use laser chaining to open the door.

[image]

- Then, use laser chaining to kill the turrets and then raise the platform. After that you can use the aerial faith plate trick with the floor again and shoot a portal where I aim the cursor…

[image]

Answer (score 9):

There's a <s>jumping pad</s> aerial faith plate. Use it!

1. Make blue portal on ground, make orange portal above jump pad, go through.
2. Gain momentum when landing on the plate, go through again.
3. Once at maximum elevation, make an *orange* portal on the wall opposite your destination. Repeat as many times as needed.

[image: Visual walkthrough]

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the aerial faith plate to gain the momentum and launch yourself onto those platforms.

**Solution:**

> Put a portal above the aerial faith plate and the second on onto the floor. Use that to launch yourself or the cubes into the air. While you're mid-air, shoot the portal that was above the aerial faith plate to a different surface in the room. This will conserve the momentum  you gain from falling down and launch you across the room.

Comment: Don't have Portal 2 at this computer, this explanation is from memory. I'll add some screens and/or details later.

Comment: It worked, though @Tom added the pictures :-)

Comment: Took some time to figure out the map, it would be easier to help people if they copied the map name out of their console. Or I should add information to the Portal II map list question. I just used my screen clipping software to take screenshots of the screenshots to quickly upload them, was fun to start out at chamber 14 and `noclip` through each chamber... xD

Answer (score 1):

Interesting - I kind of wish I had done it this way. I had a slightly different idea, which was a complete PITA on timing:

> Portals above the faith plate, and on the middle of the floor, but rather than open the new portal while at the highest point of the trajectory from the floor portal, for some reason I had it in my head I needed to set my portal while I was between the faith plate and the portal directly above it.

i.e. in that very small fraction of a second I was trying to line up and fire my portal.

It worked fine, but took way too long and made me waaayyyy to twitchy on my mouse button :-)

Comment: Haha! I'm glad I wasn't the only person who did it this way round. I had a right facepalm moment when I read this answer... *However*, I get the feeling this should really have been posted as a comment on one of the other answers, and not an answer in it's own right.